# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Comments#edit - Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a ruby on rails blog tutorial and everytime I try to edit a comment I get an error.
Error: No route matches missing required keys: [:id].

Please help I am new to this.

Error found around line 3.

```
<h1>Editing comment</h1>

3. <%= form_for([:post, @comment]) do |f| %>
4. <div class="field">
5. <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Here is my routes.rb file code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :posts do
 resources :comments
end
end
```

My Comments_controller.rb code

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
# GET /comments
# GET /comments.json
def index
 @comments = Comment.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @comments }
  end
end

# GET /comments/1
# GET /comments/1.json
def show
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @comment }
end
end

 # GET /comments/new
 # GET /comments/new.json
 def new
   @comment = Comment.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @comment }
  end
 end

 # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 end

 # POST /comments
 # POST /comments.json
 def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

   respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  # PUT /comments/1
# PUT /comments/1.json
def update
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @post = @comment.post
  respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
 end

 # DELETE /comments/1
 # DELETE /comments/1.json
 def destroy
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully deleted!' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end
 def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :name, :email, :body)
 end
end
```

Comment: What is the URL you are using for edit?

Comment: @RBK http://localhost:3000/posts/2/comments/13/edit  with 2 being the id and 13 being the post_id

Comment: Doesn't that form need to be for [@post, @comment] ?

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto If I use [@post, @comment] it shows up as undefined method `comment_path'

Comment: And which action is it calling with :post?

Comment: Since it is a nested resource, you should have /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto  Sorry I am very new to this. How do I find that info out? I believe that its looking for the id because it says its missing that.

Comment: You need to do a find on the @post in you controller's edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56499/discussion-between-user3339242-and-afonso-tsukamoto).

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto This is whats in my controllers edit. def edit 
'@'comment = Comment.find(params[:id]) 
end

Comment: resources :posts do
 resources :comments do <- you are missing a do here
end
end

Comment: then form_for([@post, @comment]) do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to leave the comments alone, let me try to explain what I think it is your problem.

In your routes file you have nested resources, which means that this:

```
resources :posts do
 resources :comments
 end
end
```

are what is called nested resources, and this means that you have routes like:

```
posts/:post_id
posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id
```

which you can see if you run `rake routes`.
This also means that the first route will call an action on your `PostsController` and the second route will call an action on your `CommentsController`.

So what I suggested you to do in your controller was to, first, render the form as `[@post, @comment]`, which will tell the `form_for` helper to use your nested resource as the 'path to send the form'. 
For this form to call your edit method you'll need to say that you want the form to be submitted there. This is done by the options for the form_for helper (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and this is necessary because rails loves/is! RESTfull, and under this, the same route might have multiple behaviours depending on the HTTP verb/method you use.

So, have attention to this that I mentioned above, and you can probably guess what you are doing wrong.

As a last hint, your controller has this:

```
 # GET /comments/1/edit
 def edit
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 end
```

And this method renders this(I assume):

```
<h1>Editing comment</h1>

<%# I already fixed the form_for here %>
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

This form, since is rendered by the edit action, will (probably) be submitted to the update action. This update action is under `/posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id`, and can be called using the PATCH(rails 4.0) verb. So your `form_for` needs, first, to have a post assigned to the variable `@post`, which should be passed by its controller. Second, it needs to go to the right route. 
Here you are lucky since Rails is smart enough to see if what you're submitting is a `new_record?` and then its `form_for` will point to create or, if not, will point to update. 
So all you need to do now, is to assign the right `Post` to `@post` and you are probably good to go.
Let me know if this worked for you.